# FFMPEG не работает и выдаёт кучу странных символов

Tags: python, telebot, ffmpeg

Я пишу telegram бота (библиотека pyTelegramBotApi) , и в одной из функции мне нужно преобразовать из .ogg в .wav, что бы перевести из аудио в текст. Я использовал эту команду

```
os.system("ffmpeg -i "+файл ogg+"  "+адрес файла wav)
```

Но после этой строки выводится такое сообщение

```
"ffmpeg" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥���������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
```

Я делал эту функцию по статье с Habr https://habr.com/ru/articles/575158/

Вот код

```
import telebot
import uuid
import os
import speech_recognition as sr

language='ru_RU'
TOKEN='YOUR_TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
r = sr.Recognizer()

def recognise(filename):
    with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
        audio_text = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio_text,language=language)
            print('Converting audio transcripts into text ...')
            print(text)
            return text
        except:
            print('Sorry.. run again...')
            return "Sorry.. run again..."

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def voice_processing(message):
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
    file_name_full="./voice/"+filename+".ogg"
    file_name_full_converted="./ready/"+filename+".wav"
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.voice.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open(file_name_full, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    os.system("ffmpeg -i "+file_name_full+"  "+file_name_full_converted)
    text=recognise(file_name_full_converted)
    bot.reply_to(message, text)
    os.remove(file_name_full)
    os.remove(file_name_full_converted)

bot.polling()
```

Пожалуйста помогите! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте при сохранении файла добавить кодировку encoding='utf-8'

Comment: Куча странных символов скорее всего из-за того что у вас в на винде локализация на русский, а ffmpeg ругается потому что у вас его вероятно просто нет, установите его. Как: https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-FFmpeg-%D0%B2-Windows, откуда: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: @kristal к сожаленью не помогло

Comment: При вводе в командной строке слова `ffmpeg` у вас **НЕ** должна появляться надпись `"ffmpeg" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.`